# Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open excel.csv for reading! File does not exist, or it is not readable

Tags: php, excel, csv

I am trying to insert data from a Excel to my database table, but it is giving me a fatal error. I don't know how to use PHPExcel library properly. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open export.xls for reading! File does not exist. in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php:433 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(269): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5->canRead('export.xls') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php(191): PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile('export.xls') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\project\import_subject_allocation.php(9): PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('export.xls') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php on line 433

I have to upload some data from a excel file to the database and I can't upload that through CSV file. I would rather not convert the XLS file into a CSV file that will be complicated and time consuming too

```
<?php
require_once 'server_config.php';
$conn=myconnection();
include "PHPExcel/IOFactory.php";
require 'PHPExcel.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST["Import"])) {
    echo $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {
        $objPHPExcel=PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
        foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            $highestrow= $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            for($row=2;$row<=$highestrow;$row++)
            {

                $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$row)->getValue());
                $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn , $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$row)->getValue());
 $query = "insert into test (`name`,`email`) values ('$name','$email')";
 $n= iud($query);
if($n){
    echo "inserted";

}else
    echo "not";
            }
        }


    }
}
?>


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="150">
        <p class="help-block">Only Excel/CSV File Import.</p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="Import" value="Import">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So what folder is the file in? Have you moved it from the temp upload folder? Otherwise, you need its temp filename. And you should be specifying a full folder path as well

Comment: it's checking the file in "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel5.php" and hadn't uploaded it anywhere this is the whole error statement that i din't understand

Comment: What folder is the export.xls file in that you're trying to load???

Comment: it is in uploads

Comment: @MarkBaker thnxx bro it is sorted out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at `PHPExcel_IOFactory::load` you need to put the file path as parameter not just the file name so do a concatenation to get that like: `$filePath."/".$fileName`

Answer (score 0):

I am using PhpSpreadsheet. PhpSpreadsheet is the next version of PHPExcel. Upgrading PHP to 7.2 solved this problem in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

i had this same error, and i solved when write all path o file.
and used this separtor / between path

my code:
$objPHPExcel  = $objReader->load("C:/xampp/htdocs/Reporte/Hoja1.xls");